# Java equivalent to C#'s TimeSpan

Tags: java, datetime, time, timespan

Does Java have a data type that represents a period of time eg 34 seconds, 5 minutes etc.

I've seen a few implementations of a TimeSpan that cover a Time period like from the 10th of December to the 11th of December.

What I need is something like TimeSpan in C#.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not a part of the JDK currently, but will be incorporated in JDK 7 - try [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I was gonna answer just that!